# JWPlayer with fancybox and oncomplete event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jwplayer

I'm using JwPlayer with fancybox, and I would like to detect when user has watched finish the video.

I tried aftershow and oncomplete but it's not working. Below is my code. Can anyone help to see what I should change to be able to detect once the video has finished playing? Thank you!

```
$(".video_show").fancybox({
                   content : '<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>',
                    fitToView : true,
                    afterShow : function() {
                        this.content = jwplayer('myElement').setup({            
                            flashplayer: "js/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                            file: this.href,
                            height: 360,
                            width: 640,
                            autoStart : false,
                            stretching : "fill"
                        }); 
                        // Store references to tag and rates
                        var videoTag;
                        var currentRate = 1;

                    },
                     events:{
                        onComplete: function() {
                            return alert("Im done");
                        }
                     }

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
stretching : "fill",
```

To:

```
stretching : "fill",
events:{
                        onComplete: function() {
                            return alert("Im done");
                        }
                     }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your answer till now. Thanks a lot for your help. That works!!